# Sort a JSON object by sub-key

Tags: json, python-3.x

I load a blob of JSON from an external site and the format is something like this:

```
{
  "Element 1": {
    "data": {
      "Year": "2021",
      "Score": "85"
    },
    "id": "00047"
  },
  "Element 2": {
    "data": {
      "Year": "2018",
      "Score": "65"
    },
    "id": "00023"
  },
  "Element 3": {
    "data": {
      "Year": "2019",
      "Score": "31"
    },
    "id": "00034"
  }
}
```

As you can see, it is sorted by the first attribute but I would like to sort it by one of the sub-attributes (forgive me if I am using the wrong terms) such as `Year` or `Score`. Ideally the end result is another JSON blob with identical information, just sorted by whichever term I choose.

I started by iterating over the whole thing, collecting the first element and Year into an array, sorting that then re-iterating over the JSON to find each sorted element.

Seems like in Python, there has to be much more elegant way.

Comment: Sorting is not important in JSON strings or in Python dictionaries. Can you elaborate why you need this? Also note that your example is not valid JSON because of trailing commas.

Comment: as @Selcuk mentioned, sorting is only applicable in arrays or lists, you can probably sort and print it, but the moment you save it back to memory, it will loose it's "sorted" property

Comment: well, insertion order *is* maintained by Python dicts. But yes, what is the ultimate goal?

Comment: Understood all re sorting and apologies for the invalid JSON - the real data is very large so I tried to summarize it.

I have a function I pass the blob to that prints it out.  I wanted to be able to print the same kind of thing but sorted by one of the other fields like Year or Score, vs the top level Element 1 etc.

Comment: What is the significance of it being an object with numbered keys? Numbered keys where order is important indicates it should be a list imo

Comment: No significance to those names.  In the real data they are product names. They are sorted alphabetically in the blob of JSON I read in - in fact, they’re keys into the rest of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need this as mentioned in the comments but you can use the `item_sort_key` argument of [`simplejson`](https://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), a third party JSON encoder/decoder for Python:

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> s = '{"Element 1": {"data": { ... }}}'
>>> d = simplejson.loads(s)
>>> d
{'Element 1': {'data': {'Year': '2021', 'Score': '85'}, 'id': '00047'},
 'Element 2': {'data': {'Year': '2018', 'Score': '65'}, 'id': '00023'},
 'Element 3': {'data': {'Year': '2019', 'Score': '31'}, 'id': '00034'}}
```

then

```
>>> simplejson.dumps(d, item_sort_key=lambda d: int(d[1]["data"]["Year"]) if "data" in d[1] else "")

'{"Element 2": {"data": {"Year": "2018", "Score": "65"}, "id": "00023"},
  "Element 3": {"data": {"Year": "2019", "Score": "31"}, "id": "00034"},
  "Element 1": {"data": {"Year": "2021", "Score": "85"}, "id": "00047"}}'
```

or

```
>>> simplejson.dumps(d, item_sort_key=lambda d: int(d[1]["data"]["Score"]) if "data" in d[1] else "")
'{"Element 3": {"data": {"Year": "2019", "Score": "31"}, "id": "00034"},
  "Element 2": {"data": {"Year": "2018", "Score": "65"}, "id": "00023"},
  "Element 1": {"data": {"Year": "2021", "Score": "85"}, "id": "00047"}}'
```

Comment: Interesting. I’ll take a look. Thank you.